# Explode a single column dataframe of ragged lists into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe consisting of a column of variable sized lists:

```
                    Col1
0         [SF, NYG, 123]
1  [SF, NYG, test, test]
2         [SF, NYG, foo]
3              [SF, NYG]
4          [SF, NYG, 45]
5              [SF, NYG]
6          [SF, NYG, 32]
```

How can I convert it to a multi-column dataframe? I would like empty values to have `NaN`, like this:

```
  Col1 Col2  Col3  Col4
0   SF  NYG   123   NaN
1   SF  NYG  test  test
2   SF  NYG   foo   NaN
3   SF  NYG   NaN   NaN
4   SF  NYG    45   NaN
5   SF  NYG   NaN   NaN
6   SF  NYG    32   NaN
```

---

I was able to come up with

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(df.Col1.tolist()).applymap(lambda x: np.nan if not x else x)
```

But I could not find a way to elegantly rename the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame` constructor with [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) for `numpy array` from `list`. Then replace `None` to `NaN` and rename columns, last [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html)

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(df.Col1.values.tolist())
           .fillna(np.nan)
           .rename(columns = lambda x: x + 1)
           .add_prefix('Col')
print (df_new)
  Col1 Col2  Col3  Col4
0   SF  NYG   123   NaN
1   SF  NYG  test  test
2   SF  NYG   foo   NaN
3   SF  NYG   NaN   NaN
4   SF  NYG    45   NaN
5   SF  NYG   NaN   NaN
6   SF  NYG    32   NaN
```

**Timings**:

```
#700
df = pd.concat([df]*100).reset_index(drop=True)

#Jez
In [10]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame(df.Col1.values.tolist()))
1000 loops, best of 3: 694 µs per loop

#cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ 
In [11]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame(df.Col1.tolist()))
1000 loops, best of 3: 705 µs per loop

#Wen
In [12]: %timeit (df.Col1.apply(lambda x: ','.join(str(y) for y in x)).str.split(',', expand=True))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.51 ms per loop

#slowier  
In [13]: %timeit (df.Col1.apply(pd.Series))
10 loops, best of 3: 159 ms per loop
```

---

```
#7k
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

#jez
In [30]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame(df.Col1.values.tolist()))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.26 ms per loop

#cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ 
In [31]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame(df.Col1.tolist()))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.37 ms per loop

#Wen
In [32]: %timeit (df.Col1.apply(lambda x: ','.join(str(y) for y in x)).str.split(',', expand=True))
10 loops, best of 3: 29 ms per loop

#very slow, the best use only in small dataframes
In [33]: %timeit (df.Col1.apply(pd.Series))
1 loop, best of 3: 1.58 s per loop
```

---

```
#700k
df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)

#jez
In [40]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame(df.Col1.values.tolist()))
10 loops, best of 3: 80.3 ms per loop

#cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ 
In [41]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame(df.Col1.tolist()))
10 loops, best of 3: 90.5 ms per loop

#Wen
In [42]: %timeit (df.Col1.apply(lambda x: ','.join(str(y) for y in x)).str.split(',', expand=True))
1 loop, best of 3: 2.91 s per loop

#extremely slow
In [3]: %timeit (df.Col1.apply(pd.Series))
1 loop, best of 3: 3min 58s per loop
```

Comment: Any other methods you can think of?

Comment: This is the best, because the fastest. you can also use `.apply(pd.Series)`, but it is very slow.

Comment: It is similar to my answer, but the renaming of columns is very elegant, so I accepted. Thank you :)

Comment: thank you, very hard find something better as dataframe constructor here

Comment: I add timings - `.apply(Series)` is really slow

Comment: Thank you! This is informative. I didn't know first getting `.values` will make such a difference. Also, I marvel at your patience for waiting 4 minutes for the test to complete :P

Comment: No 4 minutes, it was minimal 15 minutes... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do this

```
  df.var1.apply(lambda x: ','.join(str(y) for y in x)).str.split(',', expand=True).fillna(value=np.nan)
```

Comment: It's certainly a nice attempt, but the joining just to split is a bit ugly :-) Still +1, thanks for answering!